# Opendaylight REST - Create Flow

Tags: rest, sdn, opendaylight

I am using opendaylight magnesium and am trying to control a pair Northbound Networks Zodiac FX SDN switch. So far, here are a couple REST queries that I have been successful with:

```
To get all Nodes

curl -X GET -u admin:admin -f -4 http://192.168.107.22:8181/restconf/operational/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/ -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -H 'Accept: application/xml'

Get the info for one node

curl -X GET -u admin:admin -f -4 http://192.168.107.22:8181/restconf/operational/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node/openflow:123917682136241 -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -H 'Accept: application/xml'

curl -X GET -u admin:admin -f -4 http://192.168.107.22:8181/restconf/operational/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node/openflow:123917682136222 -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' -H 'Accept: application/xml'
```

If someone could help me write one REST query to create a simple flow I would be very appreciative. Something like, 
"For all packets that enter on port 1, exit port 3 and port 4." 
or
"All packets destined for MAC_ADDRESS exit port 3"

If I knew what all the field names and expected values were I could write my own, but I don't know where to get this information. Here is a query that I pulled from [ask.opendaylight.org](https://ask.opendaylight.org/question/2892/add-flow-using-rest-api-in-open-daylight-controller-helium/). The person writing this knew how to format   value   , and all the rest of the fields. I don't know where to find all available match filters and action parameters.

```
curl --noproxy 10.19.10.225 -u admin:admin -H 'Content-Type: application/yang.data+xml' -X PUT -d ' <flow xmlns="urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory"> <priority>14865</priority> <flow-name>sampleFlow</flow-name> <idle-timeout>12000</idle-timeout> <match> <ethernet-match> <ethernet-type> <type>2048</type> </ethernet-type> </ethernet-match> </match> <id>9</id> <table_id>0</table_id> <instructions> <instruction> <order>6555</order> </instruction> <instruction> <order>0</order> <apply-actions> <action> <order>0</order> <output-action> <output-node-connector>1</output-node-connector> </output-action> </action> </apply-actions> </instruction> </instructions> </flow>' 'http://10.19.10.225:8181/restconf/config/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/node/openflow:510715245500041/table/0/flow/9'
```

Any help would be great. I can't figure out the opendaylight documentation methodology. I've been digging through the help in karaf, but it isn't very comprehensive either.

As an extra kicker, in Magnesium, they did away with the GUI and they did away with the layer2 learning switch functionality. So, life is a bit tricky.

Thank you so much,

Greg

Answer (score 0):

See if this [end-to-end](https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-neon/user-guide/openflow-plugin-project-user-guide.html#end-to-end-flows) flows guide helps. I think you will want to create
a match on  and then you can [output to physical port](https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-neon/user-guide/openflow-plugin-project-user-guide.html#output-to-physical-port) with an action of output-node-connector.

let me know if you still can't figure it out.

Comment: I've read that post a million times and just about an hour ago it started making sense.  In particular, I found out how to more effectively use Yang-UI in Oxygen to drill through the available REST API.  I was previously using Magnesium, which doesn't have any GUI at all (no DLUX). Without having that GUI explorer for the REST API's I was terribly lost. 

So, in short, that link you shared is super helpful. If I could have a GUI explorer for API calls in Magnesium that would also be super helpful.  Do you know a Yang GUI (or flow builder) for Magnesium?

Comment: does this help?
http://localhost:8181/apidoc/explorer/index.html